# Raven-js errors not getting "site" property in sentry, while python raven errors are?

Tags: sentry, raven

I have three python clients and a javascript client (all raven) connecting to a single sentry server.  I have a unique `site` set for each client.  However, while errors generated by the three python clients have `site` properly set in the sentry interface, errors generated by the javascript client have no `site` set.

My raven-js setup (pardon my Django):

```
require(['lib/raven-1.0.7'], function(Raven){
  Raven.config('{% sentry_public_dsn %}', {
    // escapere is a custom tag, simply wraps python's re.escape
    includePaths: [new RegExp('{{ request.build_absolute_uri|escapere }}')],
    site: 'AJAX'
  }).install();
  Raven.setUser({
    email: "{{ user.email|escapejs }}",
    id: "{{ user.id|escapejs }}"
  });
});
```

I did a little bit of digging in the sentry code (using the highly scientific scatter-some-logging-statements-around method), and I'm convinced that the "site" parameter is, indeed, being sent to the sentry API, but for some reason it's getting lost between there and creating the actual event Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems sentry is moving away from the `site` parameter in favor of tags.  Upgrading to the latest master from the raven-js repo and changing

```
site: 'AJAX'
```

to

```
tags: {site: 'AJAX'}
```

Makes things behave as expected.